# Example of function with tricky property

Tags: measure-theory

Assume we have measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ with $\mu (X) = 1$.
What would be an example of a function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f > 0$ a.e and yet there is no $\delta > 0$ such that $f \geq \delta$ a.e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, an example could be $X=(0,1]$ with the Borel algebra and the lesbegue measure and $f(x)=x$. Then, $\mu(\{f(x)\geq \delta\})=1-\delta<1$ for any $\delta>0$.